# How to create an object in C# which inherits from IDispatch that can be incorporated into older programs that use ActiveX

Tags: c#, com, oracle10g, ole, idispatch

first time on SO though I've used the site a lot, I will get straight to the point.

**My actual end goal is to create an object which inherits from the IDispatch interface in C# which can be used in Canvases inside of Oracle Forms Builder (Oracle Developer Suite 10g (10.1.2.0.2))**

**Does anyone have any resources where I can learn how to do this or where any examples of this are shown?**

In order to achieve my goal thus far I went to this site : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24089/Create-ActiveX-in-NET-Step-by-Step

Here I got some code which allowed me to create and test an activeX object. I believe that all objects utilized by the COM structure. I then registered this using regasm and then I tried to call it. I was able to call it successful in IE.

I was about to recreate this active X object after some time; however, whenever I attempt to import it to Oracle forms I got an error like:

[image]

To me the error seems very clear, I obviously did not implement some method that oracle forms needs me to implement. What are the methods I need to implement and how should it be implemented.

Sorry for the long question, any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: Oracle Forms Builder just needs an "ActiveX Control". If you successfully run this control in IE, it should work in there. Are you sure it's not a 32/64-bit issue?

Comment: I don't believe that this is a  32/64 bit issue because of the nature of the error message. 

I did a quick google search and nothing I read on the first page indicated any possibility of 32/64 bit issues.

Furthermore, I recompiled the code to the x86 platform and I got the same error.

Comment: 32/64 bit issues are not only related to compilation, it can be also a registration issue. The error message is a pretty generic one

Comment: I see, to be honest I have haven't had any serious issues regarding 32/64 bit compatibility on this project; however, I also know that I do not have a VIEWER method implementation in the OLE object so I'm quite sure that I need to implement some interface I don't know about.

Comment: If it works in IE, it should be ok. Otherwise you can implement ICustomQueryInterface to trace QI calls and see if you see something related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you start by reading [this description in MSDN of the interfaces which ActiveX controls may expose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You will need to implement at least the minimum functionality (i.e. minimal set of interfaces) to keep the Oracle Forms Builder happy. Just implementing `IDispatch` is not sufficient.